# Sifting algorithm for group generated by a set

Tags: algorithms, group-theory

On page 38 of  "Lecture Notes in Computer Science" by Christoph M. Hoffmann, there is an algorithm (ALGORITHM 2).

I have some confusions.

[image]

Why it is written that an entry $M_{i,j}, j < i$, cannot be referenced? what is the meaning  of "reference" here?

Thanks.

Comment: Lecture Notes in Computer Science is the name of the *series*, not of the specific monograph. It's like saying 'On page 38 of "Book"'.

Comment: It feels like we are missing a lot of background here. Try to re-read the first 37 pages, and surely you'll find an answer to your question.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus I read it.  What is the meaning of "reference"  as a word (in this context) here?

Comment: It's an entry that "doesn't exist" or "hasn't been assigned". Only you can tell, since only you read the first 37 pages. Perhaps you should concentrate on the definition of *partially completed* representation matrix.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Yes I have read it but  the word reference seems out of context to me.Both 'partially completed representation matrix' and 'reference'  used for  the first time on page 38.Partially completed representation matrix is understandable, it means there are some entries in $M$ but it is not completed i.e. There are some  empty entries in $M$ .If one wants to represent $\pi$ as products of entries of $M$,  $M$ needs to be completed. We use $\pi$ to complete $M$, through 'sifting' process (line 7 to 11).But I don't get the word "reference" here. What  does it mean?

Comment: Don't use images as main content of your post. This makes your question impossible to search and inaccessible to the visually impaired; [we don't like that](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/752/should-we-do-anything-about-questions-that-are-just-a-scan-of-a-problem-in-their). Please transcribe text and mathematics (note that you can [use LaTeX](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/271/add-short-reference-for-latex-commands)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible explanation is that it is indicating that you should never try to read or use any matrix element $M_{i,j}$ where $i<j$.  "Referenced" might be talking about "de-referencing" a pointer, i.e., reading a memory cell, i.e., reading an entry of the matrix.  Perhaps the text is indicating that the matrix entries $M_{i,j}$ are only defined for $i \ge j$.

I suggest you read the text with this possible perspective in mind and see if it seems consistent with the surrounding context.